# NHibernate nullability check inside where does not work

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have this code

```
var x = xId.HasValue ? _xRepository.Get(xId) : null;
var result = _yRepository.Find()
.Where(y=> x == null || x.Ys.Contains(y)).ToArray();
```

NHibernate breaks on this line `.Where(y=> x == null || x.Ys.Contains(y))` where it executes all conditions and it does not stop on the first condition if the value of x is equal to null.

could any one help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, we can evaluate the `x` before the SQL is created e.g:

```
var toFilter = _yRepository.Find();

// should we handle x at all?
if (x != null)
{
    toFilter = toFilter.Where(y => x.ys.Contains(y));
}

var emailAddresses = toFilter.ToArray();
```

**Extend**

with an extension like this

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> MyContains<T, TFilter>(
         this IQueryable<T> list, 
         TFilter x, 
         Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterFunc)
    {
        if (x == null)
        {
            return list;
        }

        return list.Where(filterFunc);
    }
}
```

we can make such filtering at one line

```
var emailAddresses = _yRepository
   .Find()
   .MyContains(x, y => x.ys.Contains(y))
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: is there another solution to keep them on the same line.?

Comment: of course.. it is.. just create your own Extension method, which will encapsulate that IF and apply where only if exsits...

Comment: I wanted to know the other way of handling it, not using if statement, I already know that it works if we use if statement but I wanted to learn a new approach to handle it, thanks.

Comment: if edit the answer and include another way that would be great for any one reach this question.

Comment: I extended the question with a drafted Extension method which should do what you'd need. It can check passed x .. if exists.. and then apply whatever filtering... hope that helps to make it one line